# WARN - Crashlytics halted compilation because it can't extract Crashlytics build info from the APK

Tags: google-fabric

Crashlytics fails during the test.

+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                Lane Context                                                 |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| DEFAULT_PLATFORM            | android                                                                       |
| ENVIRONMENT                 | release                                                                       |
| PLATFORM_NAME               | android                                                                       |
| LANE_NAME                   | android build_and_upload_to_fabric                                            |
| GRADLE_BUILD_TYPE           | Release                                                                       |
| GRADLE_ALL_APK_OUTPUT_PATHS | ["/workspace/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk"]                  |
| GRADLE_ALL_AAB_OUTPUT_PATHS | []                                                                            |
| GRADLE_APK_OUTPUT_PATH      | /workspace/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk                      |
| FL_CHANGELOG                | • cloudbuild.yaml edited online with Bitbucket • change env • stop injecting  |
|                             | businesses into DashboardFragment                                             |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

[15:53:55]: Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap
 WARN - Crashlytics halted compilation because it can't extract Crashlytics build info from the APK: /workspace/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk
Exception in thread "main" com.crashlytics.tools.android.exception.PluginException: Distribution upload failed.
        at com.crashlytics.tools.android.DeveloperTools.processProperties(DeveloperTools.java:667)
        at com.crashlytics.tools.android.DeveloperTools.processArgsInternal(DeveloperTools.java:348)
        at com.crashlytics.tools.android.DeveloperTools.main(DeveloperTools.java:273)
Caused by: com.crashlytics.tools.android.exception.DistributionException: Crashlytics halted compilation because it can't extract Crashlytics build info from the APK: /workspace/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk
        at com.crashlytics.tools.android.DistributionTasks.uploadDistribution(DistributionTasks.java:64)
        at com.crashlytics.tools.android.DeveloperTools.processProperties(DeveloperTools.java:665)
        ... 2 more

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: This was a known issue for users of Android Gradle plugin 3.3.2, resolved with Fabric Gradle plugin version 1.28.1. Otherwise, this error indicates that our plugin can't find a crashlytics-build.properties file, might find more info here: https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/build-tools.html#optimize-builds-when-you-re-not-proguarding-or-using-beta-by-crashlytics